# Lookup Master value from another dataframe in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I need to process CSV data using Python. In CSV file(weather.csv), i received actual data which should be processed.

Before processing the data, I need to refer another CSV file for lookup for few column. File states.csv, is my lookup file. It contains only two columns (1)Id (2)State

I created two data frame , one with actual data and another for lookup data. 
I like to replace state name in df from state id from df_states. And once it's done, I would like to push the dataframe to SQL server. So major data cleanup and lookup work, I would like to do in python script.

I tried following but no luck.

```
 df=pd.read_csv("weather.csv")
 df_states = pd.read_csv("states.csv")

def lookup_state(state):
    match = (df_states['state'] == state)
    stateid = df_states['state'][match]
    return stateid.values[0]

df['state'].apply(lookup_state)
print (df)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're seeing? "no luck" isn't very descriptive.

Comment: My df does not show stateid. As I mentioned, I would like to either add stateID in df or would like to replace state with it's ID.

Comment: try look at merge

Comment: is the output of `df.set_index('state').join(df_states.set_index('state'))` what you want?

Comment: I think I figured it as below - df3=pd.merge(df,df_states,on="state")
df3=df3.drop(['state'], axis=1)
print (df3)